# Rmarkdown: Explicitly specify the figure size of a plot within a chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using RMarkdown to functionally create a document using `results = 'asis'` with a `purrr::map`.  There are multiple plots that come out of the chunk on each `purrr` iteration.  Most of them are the same size, and can be set using the chunk options for figure size.  However one or two need to have a different size.  It is not possible to separate the code into different chunks due to the way the loop/map is set up.

The closest I've found is http://michaeljw.com/blog/post/subchunkify/, however when I use this on the plot that needs different sizing, it causes the first iteration's plots that were output using the print() function to be recycled in the subchunkify's plots location.

Is there a different, less hacky way to do this?  Or is there something obvious in the subchunkify code that would be fixable?

Here is `subchunkify()`:

```
subchunkify <- function(g, fig_height=7, fig_width=5) {
  g_deparsed <- paste0(deparse(
    function() {g}
  ), collapse = '')

  sub_chunk <- paste0("
  `","``{r sub_chunk_", floor(runif(1) * 10000), ", fig.height=", fig_height, ", fig.width=", fig_width, ", echo=FALSE}",
  "\n(", 
    g_deparsed
    , ")()",
  "\n`","``
  ")

  cat(knitr::knit(text = knitr::knit_expand(text = sub_chunk), quiet = TRUE))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I haven't found an alternative to `subchunkify()`, however I did solve the issue with it reusing the same plots on each loop iteration (though I haven't dug into why it was yet).

I added an `id` argument to `subchunkify()` and included it in the file name, and then within my loop/map I created an `id` value that would be a combination of variables within each iteration that would be unique for each one.

```
subchunkify <- function(g, fig_height=7, fig_width=5, id = NULL) {
  g_deparsed <- paste0(deparse(
    function() {g}
  ), collapse = '')

  sub_chunk <- paste0("
  `","``{r sub_chunk_", id, "_", floor(runif(1) * 10000), ", fig.height=", fig_height, ", fig.width=", fig_width, ", echo=FALSE}",
  "\n(", 
    g_deparsed
    , ")()",
  "\n`","``
  ")

  cat(knitr::knit(text = knitr::knit_expand(text = sub_chunk), quiet = TRUE))
}
```

So I'm not sure why the `runif` in `subchunkify` was failing to result in distinct file names on each iteration.  My suspicion is that it has something to do with how `knitr` caching works.  I noticed that if a subsequent iteration of my loop ended up going through the same conditional chain to produce graph A, then graph A would be reused everywhere that the condition chain matched.  However if an iteration went off on a different conditional branch to produce graph B, it would correctly generate a new graph.  (However then graph B would be reused in all places with the same conditional branch ending).

This still doesn't explain why me introducing a unique file name with `id` works, but using `runif` doesn't since in both cases the file name should be unique, so this is only a guess.

So I guess if anyone else is having problems, I have a solution here but not an explanation.  Very unsatisfying but does the trick!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a list of all of the specs for the plots then use `purrr::pwalk`:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
plots <- map(1:3, ~ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point())
specs <- list(plots, fig_height = 1.5, fig_width = list(2, 3, 4))
pwalk(specs, subchunkify)
```
````

[image]

Comment: That's not the issue.  The issue is that despite the runif(), the files seem to end up with the same file name on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This might be too late but I want to share my way hacking through the reuse-plot-issue using `subchunkify()`.

The main idea of `subchunkify()` is having the plot embedded inside pseudo-subchunk. Each pseudo-subchunk need a unique name to be correctly referenced when knitting the
final document. `Subchunkify()` utilized random-number generator - `runif()` to obtain unique pname, which works most of the time except dealing with loops or complicated markdown blocks.

Based on my observation the cause of reuse-plot-issue is locked random number seed.
I suspected that knitting process mistakenly locks seed - like `set.seed()` in complicated markdown structures, which led to identical random number lists obtained from `runif()`, finally having same plots referenced at multiple locations.

Adding a suffix id could fix this problem as it preserve unique subchunk names. Another hacky way is to unlock random number seed every time `subchunkify()` is needed.

```
subchunkify <- function(g, fig_height=7, fig_width=5, id = NULL) {
  rm(.Random.seed, envir = globalenv()) # to remove locked seed
  g_deparsed <- paste0(deparse(function() {g}), collapse = '')
  sub_chunk <- paste0("
  `","``{r sub_chunk_", id, "_", floor(runif(1) * 100000), ", fig.height=", fig_height, ", fig.width=", fig_width, ", echo=FALSE}",
    "\n(", 
  g_deparsed
  , ")()",
  "\n`","``
  ")

  cat(knitr::knit(text = knitr::knit_expand(text = sub_chunk), quiet = TRUE))
}
```

`rm(.Random.seed, envir = globalenv())` is the only line of code added. For me this quick fix works like a charm.

By the way I would also encourage to have more digits in random number. `runif()` by chance can output same number with enough iterations. With `floor(runif(1) * 10000)` used for 50 embedded plots in a single markdown document, it actually have ~10% chance to have at least one collison. Do `floor(runif(1) * 1000000)` instead of `floor(runif(1) * 10000)` to decrease chance of accidentally having random number collision.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [jzadra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086777/jzadra) is fine but the ID is random. In the same spirit, I fixed this issue using the [`digest` library](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/digest/index.html), computing a hash from the object to be *subchunkified*.

```r
subchunkify = function(g, fig_height, fig_width, chunk_name = NULL) {
  g_deparsed = paste0(deparse(
    function() {
      g
    }
  ), collapse = "")

  if (is.null(chunk_name)) { # Generate a unique ID for g
    chunk_name = digest::digest(g)
  }

  sub_chunk = paste0(
    "<center>\n\n\`\`\`{r ", chunk_name,
    ", ", "fig.height=",
    fig_height,
    ", fig.width=",
    fig_width,
    ", echo=FALSE}",
    "\n(",
    g_deparsed,
    ")()",
    "\n\`\`\`\n\n</center>"
  )

  cat(knitr::knit(text = knitr::knit_expand(text = sub_chunk), quiet = TRUE))
}
```

The resulting ID is then deterministic. This would still raise an error if `subchunkify` is called twice from the same object but I guess this is reasonable.